# Facebook: How can this be done?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, external

I recently discovered this link:

https://www.facebook.com/media/albums/?id=111115269008275

I would expect this to be a facebook page but if you click on "Rezeptwelt", you get directed to a page that is not facebook. How can this be achieved?

I'd be thankful for any hint!

Edit: there's this too: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=259658517487282&id=111115269008275 - once again, when clicking on "Rezeptwelt", I am directed to a webpage (which redirects me back to facebook, but that's not the point), how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an Open Graph page, backed by a Like button on an external URL.
This functionality is [deprecated and will be removed in a few weeks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/)